# Error with backup file during restore it php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make backup file and restore it using php language with mysql database .
I can generate backup file successfully but when I restore it mysql log file show this error

```
Aborted connection 16169 to db: 'radius' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'AcctStopTime' at row 1)
```

why this error appear ? I generated this file from database

```
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+---------------
-+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          
|
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+---------------
-   +
| RadAcctId            | bigint(21)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment 
|
| AcctSessionId        | varchar(32) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                
|
| AcctUniqueId         | varchar(32) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                
|
| UserName             | varchar(64) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                
|
| Realm                | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| NASIPAddress         | varchar(15) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                
|
| NASPortId            | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| NASPortType          | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| AcctStartTime        | datetime    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                
|
| AcctStopTime         | datetime    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                
|
| AcctSessionTime      | int(12)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| AcctAuthentic        | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| ConnectInfo_start    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| ConnectInfo_stop     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                
|
| AcctInputOctets      | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                             |
 +----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+--------------
 --+
```

Comment: Please, add the table structure.

Comment: It says it in the error, why the error appears: "Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'AcctStopTime' at row 1". So, check your backup file and if the datetime values are still correct.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: but I generated backup file from database so how blank value is found in able if it not valid?